# Rspec errors after starting tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I tried to start my rspec test, and after

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec
```

I got:

```
    /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:348:in `find_and_eval_shared': Could not find shared examples "template rend
ering action" (ArgumentError)
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:309:in `block (2 levels) in define_nested_shared_group_method'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:363:in `module_exec'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:363:in `subclass'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:254:in `block in define_example_group_method'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:308:in `block in define_nested_shared_group_method'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/spec/controllers/reports_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:363:in `module_exec'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:363:in `subclass'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:254:in `block in define_example_group_method'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/spec/controllers/reports_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:363:in `module_exec'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:363:in `subclass'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:254:in `block in define_example_group_method'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:43:in `block in expose_example_group_alias'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/spec/controllers/reports_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
        from /home/nitrous/poznan-workshops-2015/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
```

I googled it but didn't find the solution. I noticed that rspec only on models works fine, but when I want to start it on controllers I get the same error.
All gems which are needed I've installed properly.

Comment: There is something wrong in `spec/controllers/reports_controller_spec.rb:11`, start there.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have to be setting the rails env. You should be able to just run `bundle exec rspec spec`.

Answer (score 1):

without ENV it's the same story.
My reports_controller_spec.rb :

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReportsController do
  let(:user) { create :user }

  before { sign_in user }

  describe 'GET #subjects' do
    subject { get :subjects }

    it_behaves_like 'template rendering action', :subjects
  end
end
```

I'm new in spec tests and I don't see errors. That's reports_controller.rb. Mayby will be helpful.

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  expose(:subject_items) { SubjectItem.includes(:teacher, :students) }
end
```